# Do you usually need install/declare anything in your frontend for CORS to be allowed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am currently working on a react/express project and I get this error:
**Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.**
I have enabled CORS in my server.js like this:

```html
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 5000,
  cors = require("cors");
  {Sequelize, Model, QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
```

I also have no issues with displaying the original data in console.
This is basically what causes it to break.

```html
allDetails=JSON.parse(details);
```

Getting and sending the data:

```html
async function connect() {
  var detailsArray=[]
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }

  info = await sequelize.query('select * from Information', { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
  let details = JSON.stringify(info);
  detailsArray=JSON.parse(details);
  return details;
}

app.get("/list", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await connect();
  res.json(result);
});
```

I also made sure to npm install for both my client and server side a few times to double check and triple check that it was installed.

Am I missing something?Or do I need anything in my client side to solve this issue. This is very confusing and whatever solution I tried for my CORS issue did not work either. Powershell is also not giving any errors regarding me trying to parse my data. I am not very familiar with cross origin related errors so an explanation would be very much appreciated.

**When this error happens:**
The error happens when I try to JSON.parse() the data received but when using console.log to display the raw data it is fine. So before that nothing breaks.

Comment: There are lots of pitfalls you can run into when debugging CORS issues so the more detail you can provide the better. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be super helpful.

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console? The *“A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development”* message cited in the question isn’t actually a CORS error — instead it’s just a React error. If it were a CORS error, it would explicitly include the literal string *CORS* in the error message.

Comment: I am unsure to what extend I can reproduce them problem since I am using a database but I will add more details to the question!

Comment: It is a react error at the front. The console said it has issues accessing the actual error so I assumed it might be related to it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are running both front-end and server on your local machine during development and getting CORS error, if so, since you are using express and have already required the CORS module, you still need to use it as a middleware to your express app - [Express - Using middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express(),
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000,
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: app.use(cors()); is this what you mean? I have already added that.Unless I did not understand middlewares properly?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Then try adding more info on the question: the port you are using on client side; you get the error when clicking/submitting something... Maybe in one of these steps we can find the problem, because as it was said in other comments, from what I know, this error is kind of a "generic error" that react throws regarding cross-origin.

Comment: Alright, I have added more information and pointed out when it happens. Hope it will give more insight to what the problem is!